# Получаю ошибку Error message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path при запуске pytest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, chromedriver

При запуске автотеста на базе python selenium получаю ошибку Error message: `"'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as eс

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
class TestAUTH:
    def test_auth(self):
        driver.get('https://qa-mesto.praktikum-services.ru/')
        driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email').send_keys('email')
        driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys('password')
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'auth-form__button').click()


        WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='root']/div/main/section[1]/div[1]")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
Установить в терминале
pip install webdriver-manager

Импортировать вот это
from selenium import webdriver from webdriver_manager.chrome import

При инициализации драйвера установить такие атрибуты
ChromeDriverManager driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())